# What is the Best Way to Migrate the SSP In SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Server 2010?

Tags: migration

What is the best way to migrate the SSP In SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Server 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this "guide": [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx)

there is a session about migrating SSPs.